# Make api data from subscribe global angular 5

Tags: angular, bind, edit

How do I make this author variable accessible in any method?

I have var author[] that assigned by api data in subscribe, the author can be property binded in html component, but shows an empty array if I check by console.log in number 1 & 3.

[image]

```
public author = [];
pengarangEdit: FormGroup;

constructor(
 private route: ActivatedRoute,
 private authorService: AuthorService,
 private location: Location,
 private fb: FormBuilder
) { }

ngOnInit() {
  this.getAuthor();
  console.log(this.author); //..................................  1
}  

createForm() {
 this.pengarangEdit = this.fb.group({
  nama: ['', Validators.required ],
  email: ['', Validators.required ],
  alamat: ['', Validators.required ]
 });
}

getAuthor(): void{
  const id = +this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');
  this.authorService.getAuthor(id)
  .subscribe(data => {
    this.author = data['data'][0]
    console.log(this.author) //.................................  2
  });
  console.log(this.author); //..................................  3
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your 1 and 3 console.log run before getAuthor() is completed and that is the reason they are still null. It is a subscription, and works like an async function. You can access author after the getAuthor() is completed.

If your change detection strategy is OnPush, do a markForCheck() after assigning author in getAuthor() function. If not, then Angular will automatically update the variable.